# Why only one argument is copied in function instead of 6?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to programming and in function below I wanted to add one argument from one list and then one argument from another list if their number is same. Instead I get one output. I don't know why.

Desired output is:
ll = [aa,ab,ba,bb,ca,cb]

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, n, s):
        self.n = n
        self.s = s

aa = TestClass("aa", 2)
ba = TestClass("ba", 2)
ca = TestClass("ca", 2)

ab = TestClass("ab", 2)
bb = TestClass("bb", 2)
cb = TestClass("cb", 2)

ls1 = [aa, ba, ca]
ls2 = [ab, bb, cb]
ml = []

def make_last_list(list1, list2, merged_list):
    a = len(list1) + len(list2)
    recently_added = 0
    while a:
        if list1 and not recently_added == "list1":
            try:
                x = list1[0]
                x = x.s
                y = list2[0]
                y = y.s
            except:
                x = list1[0]
                x = x.s
                y = 0
            if x >= y:
                merged_list.append(list1[0])
                recently_added = "list1"
                del(list1[0])
        if list2 and not recently_added == "list2":
            try:
                x = list1[0]
                x = x.s
                y = list2[0]
                y = y.s
            except:
                x = 0
                y = list2[0]
                y = y.s
            if y >= x:
                merged_list.append(list2[0])
                recently_added = "list2"
                del(list2[0])
        a -= 1
    return merged_list

make_last_list(ls1, ls2, ml)

print ml

for x in ml:
    print x.n, x.s
```

EDIT: I don't know why this question is blocked I can explain one more time what I want to achieve. I want my function to merge contents of two lists into one but in a way that if value of subclass 's' is the same it will add one **entire entry (for example aa, ab)** from one list (ls1) then one from another (ls2).

Comment: I'm trying very hard to follow your logic but I'm failing pitifully. Why do you do `if x > y` in the first condition, and `if y >= x` in the second?

Comment: Why the foo was this closed as 'off-topic'?

Comment: @decltype_auto I suspect the problem may be at least partially caused by the fact that the sample code is a bit on the confusing side. Giving variables the same name as their content tends to be hard to follow-- for instance, it gives a desired output, but does it mean a list `ll` containing the *`Cls` Objects* `aa`, `ab`, .., or the *strings* `"aa", "ab", ..`? (Also, it may want to rename `Cls` to `MyClass` or something a bit more human-languagey, since `cls` (lowercase) is used fairly frequently for other things. :s )

Comment: @Augusta: The mere low code quality does not suffice for closing a question. The q has an MVCE, the desired output was given, the algorithm described properly. And, last not least, the notion of merging lists depending on position-dependent criteria is of general interest.

Comment: @decltype_auto Oh, I know. But the quality of the example does effect the entire question's comprehensibility. A criterion for an "adequate question" is that it have a clear idea of what's wrong and what it ought to be doing in order to "work", and if the quality of the code samples interfere with that (as you can imagine it could), then people will vote to close. I don't know if that's exactly what happened, but what you see may be the result.

Comment: After the most recent change (`>` to `>=`) I seem to get the output you expect. Is there any question left here?

Comment: @ Blckknght Yes it works with same value but it break as soon as value is different than a == b. I'd like it to work with > and < as well. I'm working currently on it and I have idea in which direction I should go but I'm not sure if this the best way.

Answer (score 2):

One notable point is, in your data every class instance has `s = 2`. Now look at `make_last_list` function

After the first iteration you are appending to merged_list and setting `recently_added = 'list2'`
.

From second iteration onwards `if list1 and not recently_added == "list1"` is True but `if x>y` is False so merged_list does not change and the second if condition `if list2 and not recently_added == "list2"` is also False.

So nothing happens after first iteration. Change the `s` values to some different numbers and you will see desired output

A small enhancement. Instead of

```
merged_list.append(list1[0])
del list1[0]
```

You can just do

```
merged_list.append(list1.pop(0))
```

Comment: It's probably better to create reversed versions of your lists for the function to use `list1 = list1[::-1]` and use `pop()` instead of `pop(0)`. Lists don't like being modified at their beginning.

Comment: This is first time I see reversing list in such way. Is it better, quicker than     lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.s, reverse=True)? I've never used deque before I'll check it out. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the tip on list pop() i never knew that . and yes `deque` seems to a better idea.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Good ideas; another one would be `yield`ing the target sequence based on two iterators.